# Slick slider dots are vertically aligned

Tags: css, slick.js

My slick slider dots are positioned so that one is under another, what's happening here and how can I fix it?

> slick-theme.css:

```
.slick-dots
{
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*bottom: -25px;*/

    display: inline-block;

    /*width: 100%;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 20;

    display: inline;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

I've never seen anything like this in another persons code and I can't find any results on Google. Please help, thank you.

Comment: share the screen shot of alignment and html

Comment: @MaheswaranS http://imgur.com/a/Q7om1 This is the screenshot, I can't upload images because of reputation :(

As for the HTML code, it's just a bunch of images within a container that is then used in the jQuery code for .slick()

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to visit imgur website. for me it is restricted website

Comment: I hope this one works, http://tinypic.com/r/efiio1/9